# Cross-Browser-Problem: transform: rotateX() – JS + CSS

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I wrote this script here: https://jsfiddle.net/g130hqv4/2/

**This is what's supposed to happen:**
I move the cursor across the page and the div in the middle of the page slightly follows the position of the cursor and rotates into that direction. (Also see screenshots.)

`Screenshot-1: Cursor is in the middle of the page:`
[image: Cursor is in the middle of the page]
`Screenshot-2: Cursor is in the upper left corner:`
[image: Cursor is in the upper left corner]

While I was working on this, I used Safari and now I realised that it only works in Safari, I also tested Opera and Chrome and the div moves around as expected but it does not rotate. I though the problem had to be: `CSS3 3D Transforms`, or: `perspective: 500;`, but I checked **CanIUse.com** and it's all supported, what's going on?

–––––––––––

This is my JS:

```
var overlayDiv = document.querySelector(".hello");

var moveDivMaxX = undefined;
var moveDivMaxY = undefined;

var viewport_center = {
    x: undefined,
    y: undefined
};

var mouse = {
    x: undefined,
    y: undefined
};

var differenceX = undefined;
var differenceY = undefined;

var moveDivX = undefined;
var moveDivY = undefined;

// tilt START
var tiltX = undefined;
var titlY = undefined;
    
var MaxTiltX = 10;
var MaxTitlY = 10;
//tilt END

function load() {
    moveDivMaxX = window.innerWidth * 0.08;
    moveDivMaxY = window.innerHeight * 0.08;
    
    viewport_center.x = window.innerWidth / 2;
    viewport_center.y = window.innerHeight / 2;
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouse.x = e.x;
    mouse.y = e.y;
    
    differenceX = viewport_center.x - mouse.x;
    differenceX = differenceX * -1;
    
    differenceY = viewport_center.y - mouse.y;
    differenceY = differenceY * -1;
    
    var moveDivXinPercent = differenceX * 100 / viewport_center.x;
    moveDivX = moveDivMaxX / 100 * moveDivXinPercent;
    
    var moveDivYinPercent = differenceY * 100 / viewport_center.y;
    moveDivY = moveDivMaxY / 100 * moveDivYinPercent;
    
    
    var centerDivX = viewport_center.x - (document.querySelector(".hello").clientWidth / 2);
    var centerDivY = viewport_center.y - (document.querySelector(".hello").clientHeight / 2);
    
    overlayDiv.style.left = centerDivX + moveDivX + "px";
    overlayDiv.style.top = centerDivY + moveDivY + "px";
    
    // Tilt hello START
    tiltX = MaxTiltX / 100 * moveDivYinPercent * -1;
    titlY = MaxTitlY / 100 * moveDivXinPercent;
  
    overlayDiv.style.transform = "rotateX(" + tiltX + "deg) rotateY(" + titlY + "deg)";
    // Tilt hello END
})

window.onresize = load;
load();
```

Comment: The code seems to work in FF too. Only that the change to the rotations is so small, that it's hard to see. If you multiplied `tiltX` and `titlY` ex. by 5, then the rotations can be seen better. Why/how the rotations are bigger in Safari, I can't say, as I don't have Safari at hands to test.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you for that information! I just figured it out, this helped me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heureka! I found the problem:

I changed this: `perspective: 500;` to this: `perspective: 500px;`

I, again, tested this in Safari, Opera and Chrome and it works. :)

Comment: Can someone accept this answer? – I can't and this solves the problem… @Teemu

Comment: Only you can accept an answer in this post. There might be some kind of grace period before you can accept your own answer.